# How do I delay the appearance of an animated scrolling background (CSS)?

Tags: css, animation

I have a sequence of animations, each delayed to appear one after the other. 
Sequence:

1. Logo
2. h1
3. hr
4. background starts scrolling upwards

Using `animation-fill-mode: backwards` each element does not appear on the page until it is animated-in. I would like the same to happen to the background. So it does not appear until all the other animations are complete. The background would then start scrolling upwards.

```css
/*Top Gif*/

.banner {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}

.opening {
  display: block;
  background: url(http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/footer_lodyas.png);
  animation: 100s scroll infinite linear;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: background;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}

.textBox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.logo {
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.logo--animated {
  animation: popUp 1s ease-out;
}

.textBox h1 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0px 8px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 18px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  line-height: 50px;
  animation: moveInRight 0.7s ease-out;
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

hr.style-two {
  border: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  animation: moveInRight 0.4s ease-out;
  animation-delay: 1.9s;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

.textBox h4 {
  line-height: 10px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  animation: moveInRight 0.6s ease-out;
  animation-delay: 2.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}


/*Animations*/

@keyframes scroll {
  100% {
    background-position: 0px -3000px;
  }
}

@keyframes popUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes moveInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-80px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="banner opening">
      <div class="opening">
        <div class="textBox">
          <img class="logo logo--animated" src="logo.png">
          <h1>Title</h1>
          <hr class="style-two">
          <h4>Sub-Title</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the background just need to appear in place and then scroll the position, or actually scroll into position from the bottom up?

Comment: For this it's sufficient for it to just appear. Though I would be interested to find out about the other option as well

Comment: I added an answer for it to just appear. I'm not sure the other option is possible without some JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the background to just appear, try this.

```css
/*Top Gif*/

.banner {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}

.opening {

  animation-delay: 5s;
  display: block;
  animation: 100s scroll infinite linear;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}

.textBox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.logo {
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.logo--animated {
  animation: popUp 1s ease-out;
}

.textBox h1 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0px 8px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0px 18px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  line-height: 50px;
  animation: moveInRight 0.7s ease-out;
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

hr.style-two {
  border: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  animation: moveInRight 0.4s ease-out;
  animation-delay: 1.9s;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

.textBox h4 {
  line-height: 10px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  animation: moveInRight 0.6s ease-out;
  animation-delay: 2.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}


/*Animations*/

@keyframes scroll {
0% {
  background-image: url(http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/footer_lodyas.png);
}
  100% {
  background-image: url(http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/footer_lodyas.png);
    background-position: 0px -3000px;
  }
}

@keyframes popUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes moveInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-80px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="banner opening">
      <div class="opening">
        <div class="textBox">
          <img class="logo logo--animated" src="logo.png">
          <h1>Title</h1>
          <hr class="style-two">
          <h4>Sub-Title</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The delayed appearance works but now the animation is not infinite. It disappears after a short while.

Comment: @mundaneMeta I edited the code. Apologies, I didn't wait the 100s ;)